# UITableView Index Out of Range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm having crashes issues with a tab app and I really can't figure out the solution. When app first executes and when I select the third tab item (weathercast), everything works fine, table data is loading with all data in it and everything displays properly, user can interact without any problems. When I'm selecting another tab item and then go back to the weathercast one, the crashes issues occur. My concern is that sometimes it crashes but sometimes it doesn't.. this is what I really cannot understand, why would it work once even several times in a row and sometimes it crashes at first try.. I suppose that at some point in the view lifecycle when viewdidAppear loads, my arrays are not filled in time thus TableView is trying to access an array element that doesn’t exist and crashes. This is what I've tried to manage using threads and dispatchQueue but still problem occurs..

Any ideas ? Thanks very much for your help.

Sometimes I've got this error message:

> 2017-12-09 14:19:11.431048+0100 Le Baluchon[19344:5162393] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

But very often, I've got this error message next to line 73 in VC:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Any ideas?

Here is my VIewController:

```
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var weatherView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherDataLoading: UIActivityIndicatorView!

let error = Notification.Name(rawValue: "Error")
var selectedRow: Int?
var count: Int = 0
var names = [String]()
var temps = [String]()
var dates = [String]()
var climates = [String]()
var forecastDates = [String]()
var forecastClimates = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.weatherView.dataSource = self
    self.weatherView.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(displayErrorAlert), name: error, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    WeatherRequest.getWeatherCast(completion: { (names, temps, dates, climates, forecastdates, forecastclimates) in
        self.names = names
        self.temps = temps
        self.dates = dates
        self.climates = climates
        self.forecastDates = forecastdates
        self.forecastClimates = forecastclimates
        self.weatherView.reloadData()
        self.weatherDataLoading.isHidden = true
    })
}

@objc func displayErrorAlert() {

    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Couldn't retrieve data from servor", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "table_cell", for: indexPath) as! WeatherViewCell

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    cell.firstStackView.constant = tableView.frame.height / 4
    cell.cityName.text = names[indexPath.item]
    cell.cityDate.text = dates[indexPath.item]
    cell.cityClimate.text = climates[indexPath.item]
    cell.cityTemp.text = temps[indexPath.item]

    cell.firstForecastedClimate.text = forecastClimates[count]
    cell.firstForecastedDate.text = forecastDates[count]
    count += 1
    cell.secondForecastedClimate.text = forecastClimates[count]
    cell.secondForecastedDate.text = forecastDates[count]
    count += 1
    cell.thirdForecastedClimate.text = forecastClimates[count]
    cell.thirdForecastedDate.text = forecastDates[count]
    cell.isExpanded = false

    count += 8

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WeatherViewCell
        else { return }

    selectedRow = indexPath.item

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5

    cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded

    self.weatherView.beginUpdates()
    self.weatherView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WeatherViewCell
        else { return }

    self.weatherView.beginUpdates()
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1
    cell.isExpanded = false
    self.weatherView.endUpdates()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    guard let selectedRow = selectedRow else { return }
    guard let cell = weatherView.cellForRow(at: [0,selectedRow]) as? WeatherViewCell
        else { return }
    cell.isExpanded = false
    weatherView.beginUpdates()
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1
    weatherView.endUpdates()
    clear()
}

func clear() {
    count = 0
    names = [String]()
    temps = [String]()
    dates = [String]()
    climates = [String]()
    forecastDates = [String]()
    forecastClimates = [String]()
}
}
```

And here is the class where I fetch data from API Yahoo Weather.

```
class WeatherRequest {

static func getWeatherCast(completion: @escaping ([String], [String], [String], [String], [String], [String]) -> ()) {

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

var names = [String]()
var temps = [String]()
var dates = [String]()
var climates = [String]()

var forecastDates = [String]()
var forecastClimates = [String]()

    let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%20in(%22Miami%22%2C%20%22new%20york%22%2C%20%22chicago%22%2C%20%22philadelphia%22))%20and%20u%3D'c'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let myData = data else { return }

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: myData)
            for channel in root.channels {
                dates.append(channel.item.condition.date)
                temps.append(channel.item.condition.temp + " °C")
                climates.append(channel.item.condition.text)
            }

            for channel in root.channels {
                for forecast in channel.item.forecast {
                    forecastDates.append(forecast.date)
                    forecastClimates.append(forecast.text)
                }
            }
            names = ["Miami", "New York", "Chicago", "Philadelphia"]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(names, temps, dates, climates, forecastDates, forecastClimates)
            }

        } catch let fetchError {
            print(fetchError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
}
}
```

Comment: You have a property `count` which you manipulate in `cellForRowAt`, but there is no specific order in which `cellForRowAt` is called, and it may be called multiple times for the same index path, so it is quite possible for `count` to exceed the size of your array. Rather than having multiple related arrays, you should have a single array of a struct that you put your retrieved data into.  Also, when you fetch new data, you don't clear old data from your array properties first

Comment: thanks for your answer, I guess it explains the fatal error message. I've used an array of struct that contains all my data fetched from the API and used with indexPath to display what I need, thus I don't need the count variable anymore. It seems to work perfectly for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The error clearly explains it. When begin updates and end updates are called, the number of rows are checked like this. Number of rows after update should be equal to number of rows before update plus or minus the rows added or deleted. In your case , the api returns 4 values but when you change tabs and come back the count changes to 0 (api response delays here). Hence before update 4 and after update 0 but delete cell is not called. For more info read the description of beginupdates, its clearly documented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your advices. I will have a look at it. What I did following Paul's answer above seemed to have resolved all the crashes issues.